# iOS5 Objective-C library for numerical analysis or GNU Octave wrapper class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, octave, numerical-analysis, kalman-filter

I'm doing some **numerical estimation and correction with the Kalman filter**, and would like to better estimate my parameters of Q and R, preferably dynamically.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Estimation_of_the_noise_covariances_Qk_and_Rk

That article mentions that **GNU Octave** is currently the best way of determining these parameters from data:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#C.2B.2B_integration
Unfortunately it is written for Matlab, and there's supposedly a C++ implementation. **I'm very weak in C++** and would not even know how to import a C++ library and link it properly in XCode. All of my C++ libraries to date have been wrapped in 3rd party Objective-C classes.

Has anyone used the C++ implementation for scientific computing or engineering applications on iPhone? I'd appreciate any pointers or tutorials on how to do this kind of analysis with Objective-C.

Additional keywords:
estimating covariance from data

Autocovariance Least-Squares (ALS) technique

noise covariance

Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to tune the filter (as it seems -- "would like to better estimate my parameters of Q and R") then why not do it off-line on a PC? The iPhone application only needs these improved matrices, there is no need to run GNU Octave on an iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any such C++ library, if you fancy doing numerical analysis on iOS, the best way to go is the [accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html), specifically (from this [description](http://developer.apple.com/performance/accelerateframework.html)):

> Linear Algebra: LAPACK and BLAS
>
> The Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS) and Linear Algebra Package
>   (LAPACK) libraries contain—as you would expect—functions to perform
>   linear algebra computations such as solving simultaneous linear
>   equations, least squares solutions of linear equations, and eigenvalue
>   problems. The BLAS library serves as a building block for the LAPACK
>   library. The BLAS and LAPACK libraries are widely distributed and
>   industry standard computational libraries. They are available on a
>   number of different platforms and architectures. So, if you are
>   already using these libraries you should feel right at home, as the
>   APIs are exactly the same on Mac OS X.

You'll need a fairly good grounding in C, pointers, arrays and such though, no way around it I feel. There is a [detailed description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FKF/FKF.pdf) of how to use these linear algebra primitives to implement kalman filtering (although this is using R, so probably not of mush use to you).

This is a [SO post on Kalman Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478881/kalman-filtering-for-programmers) which expressed my opinion quite well. I'm afraid I think the chances of finding a magic Objective-C wrapper for Kalman Filtering are fairly low, though I would be very happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: I have a working implementation of Kalman Filter in Objective C. I need to read the licence for it to figure out if I can post it on SO. Currently it estimates stuff really well, what I'm trying to do is fine-tune the filter to make it even better.